# CreateMutex with initialOwner set to TRUE makes the creator process keep the mutex till it's done

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, winapi, mutex

I have two processes, one writes in a memory mapped file - the `producer` - while the other reads from the memory file - the `consumer`.

The first process creates the mutex using the `CreateMutex()` function with the `initialOwner` parameter set to `TRUE`

The code is as follows:

producer:

```
mutexHandle = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, TEXT("producerMutex"));
while (condition)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE);
    // write a random number in the memory mapped file;
    // pause the program and prompt the user to open consumer process; do this only one time 
    ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);
}
```

consumer:

```
mutexHandle = OpenMutex(SYNCRONIZE , FALSE, TEXT("producerMutex"));
while (condition)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE);
    // read from the file, print it in terminal
    ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);
}
```

The problem is that if the `initialOwner` is set to `TRUE` the consumer will not get access to the mutex until the `producer` is done. Why is that? The application works if the `initialOwner` is set to `FALSE`, but shouldn't it work with it set on `TRUE` as well?

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE)` in the consumer makes no sense. The second parameter of `OpenMutex` is a `BOOL`, not a `HANDLE`.

Comment: If they are both waiting who is going to release the mutex?

Comment: When `intialOwner` is `TRUE` the creator locks the mutex immediately, and needs one extra `ReleaseMutex` the release that lock.

Comment: @Jodocus sorry, I wrote that from the top of my head. I changed it to FALSE (do not need for children to inherit).

Comment: @VTT the producer aquires the mutex initially and before releasing it, it prompts the user to open the second process and press any key afterwards, thus the second process (consumer) is blocked in WaitForSingleObject() until the producer releases it again.

Comment: you need skip first call `WaitForSingleObject` in producer loop. fro example `goto __0; do { WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE); __0: dosomething(); RealeaseMutex(mutexHandle);} while(condition);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`ReleaseMutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685066.aspx) documentation:

> to release its ownership, the thread must call **ReleaseMutex** one time
>   for each time that it obtained ownership (either through **CreateMutex**
>   or a wait function).

In this code:

```
mutexHandle = CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, TEXT("producerMutex"));
while (condition)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE);
    // write a random number in the memory mapped file;
    // pause the program and prompt the user to open consumer process; do this only one time 
    ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);
}
```

You obtaining the mutex lock `N+1` times - 1 time via `CreateMutex()` with `bInitialOwner=TRUE`, and `N` times in the loop via `WaitForSingleObject()`. But you release it only `N` times in the loop.  As a result, you still hold the mutex lock after the loop, until the thread exits.

To resolve this, you need to skip the first call to `WaitForSingleObject` in the loop - really, you are already the owner of the mutex and this call is not needed.  You can write code like this:

```
if (mutexHandle = CreateMutex(0, TRUE, L"producerMutex"))
{
    goto __firstTime;
    do 
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutexHandle, INFINITE);
__firstTime:
        // write a random number in the memory mapped file;
        ReleaseMutex(mutexHandle);
        // pause the program and prompt the user to open consumer process; do this only one time 
    } while (condition);

    CloseHandle(mutexHandle);
}
```

You need to call `ReleaseMutex()` just after you finish accessing the shared resource. Never "pause" the program while you hold the mutex lock.  First release it, then pause.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the description of the `initialOwner` parameter:

[CreateMutex function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx):

> If this value is TRUE and the caller created the mutex, the calling thread obtains initial ownership of the mutex object. Otherwise, the calling thread does not obtain ownership of the mutex. To determine if the caller created the mutex, see the Return Values section.

You need to call `ReleaseMutex()` on the mutex after information is ready to be consumed.

Comment: I am releasing the mutex after the info is ready, should I do it twice because of that `TRUE` parameter?

Comment: @AlexandruAntochi - you *must call ReleaseMutex one time for each time that it obtained ownership (either through CreateMutex or a wait function).* however you obtained mutex `n+1` time when release it `n` time